Multivariable chain rule for function with one negative component
I have a (smooth) function $\psi:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}\: : \: (y_1,y_2) \mapsto \psi(y_1,y_2)$. Now I want to calculate the partialderivative of $\psi(-y_1,y_2)$ with respect to $y_1$. I thought of writing $\psi(-y_1,y_2) = (\psi \circ f)(y_1,y_2)$ where $f(y_1,y_2) = (-y_1,y_2)$ and then applying the chain rule. To do this I wrote $u_1 = -y_1, u_2 = y_2$.
$$
\frac{\partial \psi(-y_1,y_2)}{\partial y_1} = \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial u_1}(u_1,u_2) \frac{\partial u_1}{\partial y_1} + \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial u_2}(u_1,u_2) \frac{\partial u_2}{\partial y_1}  
$$
and since $\partial_{y_1} u_2 = 0$ and $\partial_{y_1} u_1 = -1$ we get:
$$
\frac{\partial \psi(-y_1,y_2)}{\partial y_1} = -\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial u_1}(u_1,u_2) 
$$
Now I was wondering if we can rewrite the right hand side to some derivative of $y_1$ instead of a derivative of $u_1$.
Any help would be appreciated.

Beautiful use of tags. Congratulations.

I understand the motivation behind the question, but I think there is a misunderstanding about what the differential operators indicate.
Your equation can be written as
$$\frac{\partial (\psi\circ f)}{\partial y_1}(y_1,y_2) = -\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial u_1}(f(y_1,y_2)).$$
Here the notation is a bit confusing because it makes you think that the derivative cares about the names of the variables you are using. It does not. Both functions $\psi\circ f$ and $\psi$ are simply functions of two variables, and the operators $\partial/\partial y_1$ and $\partial/\partial u_1$ mean the same thing: differentiate with respect to the first variable keeping the second one fixed. It's a shame that this notation forces us to use two symbols for the same operation. To make this clear, instead of writing $\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial y_1}$ and $\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial y_1}$ I will write $D_1\psi$ and $D_2\psi$. Then your equation simply reads
$$D_1(\psi\circ f)(y_1,y_2) = -D_1\psi(f(y_1,y_2))$$
i.e.
$$D_1(\psi\circ f)(y_1,y_2) = -D_1\psi(-y_1,y_2).$$
I hope this helps.

That explains it! Thank you very much.
